# Blocking IP Range in .htaccess Problem

Tags: security, apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to block the access of one of my webapps using IP Filter in the .htaccess, the problem is that after updating the file with:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 58.14.0.0/15
allow from all
```

I get the folowing error:

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@example.org and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.*

What is wrong?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your server's [ErrorLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog) and also check if [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set to a sensible value.

Comment: <Directory "/home/xxxxxx/www/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
  </Directory>

Comment: ...which obviously is not your ErrorLog.

Comment: I know is not my error log!!!! Is the part of my vhost where i'm defining the AllowOverride!

Comment: There's `AllowOverride FileInfo` in your Apache httpd configuration which is not sufficient. You should really read the documentation section I linked in my answer…